# Hibernate: @ManyToMany Relationship produces duplicate entries

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, many-to-many

I am having trouble with @ManyToMany Relationships in Hibernate. The following code produces duplicate entries in the `Profession` Table:

`User`

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
open class User(
    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST])
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "benefit_id")])
    var professions: MutableSet<Profession> = HashSet(),

    ...

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private var id: Long = 0
) {

    constructor(signup: UserRequest, givenRoles: Set<Role>) :
            this(...) {

        signup.professions.forEach { profession ->
            professions.add(profession)
        }
    }
}
```

`Profession`

```java
@Entity
class Profession(
    var umbrellaTerm: String,

    var specialization: String,

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    private var id: Long = 0
){

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Profession

        if (umbrellaTerm != other.umbrellaTerm) return false
        if (specialization != other.specialization) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = umbrellaTerm.hashCode()
        result = 31 * result + specialization.hashCode()
        return result
    }
}
```

Desired behavour: There are only a limited amount of options for the Professions, so I want users that have the same profession to point to the same profession.

Actual behaviour: For every new User i persist a new row is added to the professions table even if `umbrellaTerm` and `specialization` are the same.

I already tried a lot of different options, but none of them seem to work.